# Old legacy code vs new features and libraries

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have read the somewhat same question on SO which was closed as off topic. My question is also related to and also not related to that question.

We have multiple desktop applications which were written in Vb.net using .Net framework 2.0. We have planned to upgrade our existing applications to 3.5. Following are the key confusions that currently we are experiencing.

We have been suggested that instead of upgrading to 3.5 we should upgrade to 4.5 directly regardless that we are not using any new feature of either 3.5 or 4.5. It is being suggested that upgrading to 4.5 requires no extra work and will be beneficial to us in the future. We are not able to decide to which upgrade we should use.

There is some old code meant for processing the HTML text. We are currently using SubString and IndexOf to create logic for extracting and processing relevant data. We have also being suggested to use HtmlAgility pack in this scenario along with Regex. We are not sure if this is the right course of action. I have been not very fond of external libraries. Are they more efficient and beneficial then the old native code like SubString and IndexOf. We don't want to go in something which in future cause more problem then good. I am always being suspected towards external libraries that they are not good enough and have unknown and unreported bugs.

We are using old style code like using Arrays and sizing them on runtime using Dim Redim. It is also being suggested that we should use ArrayList or other colelctions objects and should upgrade our old code.

This requires a lot of work and a lot of change. We are not very fond of the change at this stage as it can disturb our existing operations. The answer to this question could be very brief. We just want to clear ourselves that when should we have to upgrade our code and whether the external libraries like HtmlAgilityPack or technologies like Regex can be more effective and efficient.

I am sorry if it seems off topic but this is related to the planning and up gradation to our .Net Framework code.

Comment: I am sorry but your question is off-topic on SO. If you already consulted an expert and got relevant recommendations, it is up to you to decide.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you. Ok I am happy to close the question myself. But kindly understand this that we have no way to find out that whether the developer suggesting this is right or wrong. This was the reason for me to share this here.

Comment: There are **a lot** of questions there. It would be irresponsible to answer solely based on your characterizations rather than looking at the project in detail.  BUT, going to 4.5x would not cost more than just going to 3.5, it would open more doors.  Parsing HTML was probably never a good idea. You could scan Qs here to see what actual users of HtmlAgility think; the most viewed Q here is regarding RegEx for HTML parsing.  Dim/Redim were passe in Net 2.0 which had arraylist; today use collections and generics.  On the surface, I think you got good advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer: take the developer's advice. Keep up with the newest technologies that make code more reusable, readable and generic.

When we moved from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0, the code became easier to maintain and its amount got reduced. It is also more secure compared to .NET2.0, but obfuscation is still a must if you plan to release commercial products.

As for parsing HTML, the latest release of HtmlAgilityPack works flawless for basic HTML parsing operations. It can surely be combined with regular string methods and Iin case of more complex pattern extractions, with regex.

I hope my answer will be of value to you.